# Shrunk windows partition and now cannot boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've been using a dual-booted machine for a few years and my Linux partition kept running out of space. I booted up windows and used disk management to shrink down the windows partition, so that I could use it for my Ubuntu partition (I had done this before and nothing went wrong). When I restarted my laptop, it went straight to the GRUB2 command line and not the usual boot selection screen.

I researched on this forum and followed the steps here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot) but could not find the correct Grub files anywhere.

I then created a live USB and ran boot-repair, which returned this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZPMYCjCRfj/  (The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.)

I also checked GParted and it cannot detect any file systems on nvme0n1p2 & nvme0n1p4.

I'm unsure of what to do next, if anyone has any ideas I would very much appreciate it! Ideally I would be able to get my previous Ubuntu environment back, but if my machine is too messed up then I would be open to completely wiping my machine and downloading Ubuntu again.

Thank you,
Shiv

Comment: If you boot from an Ubuntu live USB, can you mount your Ubuntu partition and access it?

Comment: Did you resolve this? Currently experiencing the same issue. I resized the windows partition and can no longer boot into Ubuntu, and the ubuntu partition seems to have disappeared.