# unable to boot into ubuntu after resizing windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu alongside windows (The option called: "installing Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager")

Quickly realizing that I had not allocated a sufficient amount of space, I rebooted into Windows, and shrunk the partition by some ~50gb.

Now when I try to boot into ubuntu it goes straight to grub (not rescue), and I have a bunch of options using ls (i.e (`hd0), (hd1), (hd0,gpt1)` ...) None of them however resolve into a linux file system with an obvious boot/grub. The best I get is a folder on /efi/boot/ubuntu that contains `bootx64.efi, fbx64.efi, mmx64.efi`.

I believe this question is related:
[Shrunk windows partition and now cannot boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414084/shrunk-windows-partition-and-now-cannot-boot?newreg=0be0f0158d2c4fb8b8ff4b01bc607d00)

Boot-repair does not want to take action and does not show my linux partition, only "Free Space". Booting into a "Try Ubuntu"  and inspecting partitions only reveals my windows partition.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you know which partition is your root, eg sda1, sdb1 etc? In bash-grub if you type ls (hd0,1)/ do you see the familiar root files, eg - usr, etc, home, mnt, vmlinuz? Also hd1 suggests you have 2 disks.

Comment: No. hd1 is my usb with my live disk. And yes sda3 is my root in which windows resides, other than that there are no meaningful partitions, just “free space”. ls(hd0)/  is unknown (just the disk?), ls (hd0,gpt1) is some soort of loader which has a /efi/ubuntu with grubx64.efi shimx64 etc. (hd0,gpt2) contains unknown filesystem (ubuntu???) gpt3 is windows and I think gpt 4 is also windows but the booter. I think my ubuntu root files were on gpt2 where it now says unknown filesystem — ?

Comment: I don’t really understand what happend. Did ubuntu not properly create a partition when installing? I recall that when I shrunk the windows partition there was no sort of ext partition that would have presumable been used by ubuntu, just the windows partition and free space (& MBR) - Did I by shrinking somehow corrupt the nonexisting ubuntu partition, if so how?

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu and did not use automatic partitioning this time :/